# Latitude or longitude is not Working after Change Language

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, globalization

I am Developing multilingual in my .Net MVC 4 Application but i am facing some issue regarding latitude and longitude.When i pass my latitude and longitude from my View to Controller after selecting "Spanish" language, ModelState shows latitude and longitude is not in valid format.But it perfectly works while i select "English" Language.
Please help me out from this problem.
Any effort will appreciated.

Comment: Expand the details, show some of your code.

Comment: What is the culture of your server? Are your values typeof `decimal`?

Comment: Far too many unknowns here. Not working where? Where's the code? We have absolutely no idea what relationship of language is to your variables without you showing that connection